# Tracking JS object tracker eyes

Tags: javascript, event-handling, face-detection, tracking.js

I'm using Tracking JS to help detect if a users eyes are open and then only playing audio if it detects less than 3 objects, face, mouth, and one eye. I have it mostly convinced and working but the event is tracking and updating the data way too frequently, resulting in a very choppy and jarring experience.

Currently, I have the tracker checking constantly with the tracker on as follows:

```
  tracker.on('track', function(event) {

      if (event.data.length > 2 ) {
          document.body.classList.add("hide");
          pauseAudio();
      } else {
          document.body.classList.remove("hide");
          playAudio();
      }
```

Is there a way to run this function less frequently or specify how many times it should run per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some sort of throttling mechanisem, [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#throttle) has it build it.

`_.throttle`, gets a function & time of throttling, and returns a throttled function, so you can use it as:

```
const handler = function(event) {

      if (event.data.length > 2 ) {
          document.body.classList.add("hide");
          pauseAudio();
      } else {
          document.body.classList.remove("hide");
          playAudio();
      }
};
const throttledHandler = _.throttle(handler, 100); // 100ms
tracker.on('track', throttledHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks @felixmosh, that's exactly what I was looking for. Good to know and remember!